# Writing to a socket from one thread and reading from another

Tags: qt, qt5

i am new to qt and trying to implement client server program. At client side I want to write from one thread(main) and read socket from another, but I get following notification.

QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread
[ Tue Jan  8 15:21:19 2019] SW Update File Transfered"

It do reads the socket but it gives this notifciation. Do I have to worry about it or just ignore it?

the code is as follows.

**tcp_client.h**

```
namespace Ui {
class TCP_Client;
}

class TCP_Client : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit TCP_Client(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
MyThread *mThread;
~TCP_Client();
private slots:
void on_pushButton__SW_Update_clicked();
public:
Ui::TCP_Client *ui;
TCP_clientClass *client;
};
```

**tcp_client.cpp**

```
void on_pushButton__SW_Update_clicked{  
/*some work done here*/
 client->tcpSocket->write(buffer,16);
 mThread = new MyThread(client->tcpSocket,this);
 mThread->start();
}
```

**mythread.h**

```
class MyThread : public QThread
{  
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(QTcpSocket *ID, QObject *parent =0);
    void run ();
    bool Stop;
signals :
    void NumberChanged(QByteArray a);
public slots : 
private:
    QTcpSocket *socket1;
    };
```

**mythread.cpp**

```
MyThread::MyThread(QTcpSocket *ID,QObject *parent) : QThread(parent)
{
socket1 = new QTcpSocket();
socket1=ID;
}  

void MyThread::run()
{
QByteArray a;
qDebug()<<"Inside running thread";
socket1->waitForReadyRead(-1);
a= socket1->readAll();
qDebug() << a;
}
```

Basically, I am writing when button is pushed and inside I create a thread so that it can read data sent by server.

Comment: In your `MyThread` constructor you have `socket1 = new QTcpSocket();` followed immediately by `socket1=ID;`.  If that *is* the real code then it's a memory leak and almost certainly not what you intended.

Comment: On a side note, most `QObject` derived classes such as `QTcpSocket` are designed and implemented in such a way as to not require any extra threads on the part of user code -- just connect to the relevant signals and respond accordingly.  Rather than starting a new thread just to call `socket1->waitForReadyRead(-1);` you should connect to the `QTcpSocket::readyRead` signal and read the data as/when it becomes available.

Comment: Thank you very much! your idea did helped alot.